# How to evaluate a sympy equation with dictionary of values

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I am working on something which can automatically substitute the value in a equation and solve it.
Suppose the sympy equation is `F=(G*m1*m2)/r**2` and I have a value dict of `{'G':6.6743,'m1':1,'m2':2,'r':1}` and I want to calculate the value of F how to I automatically evaluate the sympy equation with this value. In certain cases the value might not be present and hence we might need to automatically identify the symbols and select a random value for them. Also this equation might have complex integration or differentiation equation.How can it be achieved?.

Comment: Here eqn is F=(G*m1*m2)/r**2. Thought to mention as * disappeared after posting the question

Comment: `*` is used for formatting text to italic, for code use `\`` or 4 blanks indentation.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use [`evalf`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/numeric-computation.html#subs-evalf) with the `subs` argument:

```
...
values = {'G': 6.6743, 'm1': 1, 'm2': 2, 'r': 1}
F = (G * m1 * m2) / r**2
F.evalf(subs=values)
```

Comment: Or just `F.subs(values)`